# Insert copied cells from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy all rows that have a specific value in column E and then insert them (NOT PASTE! so i want to insert new rows start at cell A29) on another sheet.

The sheet I want to copy from is called "owssvr" and the one I want to copy to is called "AOB Approval Form". I want to insert the copied rows starting Cell A29 in the "AOB Approval Form".

When i run the code, nothing happens. No error message pops up.

Few definition of my code below:
LastRow: The last row of the "owssvr" sheet

PrimaryAOB: value that i want to lookup for in column 5. It is on the "AOB Approval Form" sheet

Here is my code:

```
For k = 2 To lastRow
    If Worksheets("owssvr").Range("E" & k).Value = primaryAOB Then
    Worksheets("owssvr").Rows(k).Copy
    Worksheets("AOB Approval Form").Rows(k + 27).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next k
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: Is `primaryAOB` defined elsewhere in your code? Or does "primaryAOB" appear literally in column E?

Comment: Is the IF statement passing? Set a breakpoint in the if block and see if it hits.

Comment: Thank you guys! you really helped me! But I have a question. If i want to "delete" the added line how do I do that? I mean if I press the button new lines are added over the already added line. How can i re-start from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into a new module in a blank workbook, then made the necessary mods to make it run (which it did). It looks the same as yours:

```
Sub Question()
Dim k As long, lastRow As Long
Dim primaryAOB As String

lastRow = Sheets(1).Range("E" & (ActiveSheet.Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row
primaryAOB = Sheets(2).Range("A1").Text
For k = 2 To lastRow
    If Worksheets("owssvr").Range("E" & k).Value = primaryAOB Then
    Worksheets("owssvr").Rows(k).Copy
    Worksheets("AOB Approval Form").Rows(k + 27).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next k
End Sub
```

Since this worked, you may have just had some little syntax error somewhere while defining the variables. show us more of your procedure, that may reveal the issue! Also, have you run your code line by line? (F8)

Comment: Reverus THANK YOU! it worked! But I have a question. If i want to "delete" the added line how do I do that?

Comment: I mean if I press the button new lines are added over the already added line. How can i re-start from the beginning?

Comment: At work now, but I'll work that option into the code by this evening ;)

Comment: It is ok Reverus. I figured it out! Thanks for your help!